# Is it possible to print multiple cfreport in a single print job easily?

Tags: coldfusion, cfreport

What's the easiest way to print multiple cfreport in a single print job?

The only method I can think of is to output each report to a PDF individually, then merge the PDFs into one big PDF, and print that PDF.

Is this the only way?  Can I do something similar with FlashPaper?  FlashPaper is much easier especially with non-English characters involved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF then Merge them in memory is the solution I picked.  However, it takes time to generate it so I made use of  in CF9.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably kludge something together with a "master" report and using the other reports as sub-reports.

Comment: Thx for the idea, I'll look into it but I don't think it'll work.  The documentation is quite sparse on that.